# Postgres: How to drop a schema which has a double quote included in its name?

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have a schema called `"tenant__xyz"` in my db but need to drop it.

How can I do this?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double the double quotes (similar to doubling the single quotes in a string value)

```
drop schema """tenant__xyz""";
```

Comment: Yes, and don't create the new schema with double quotes. You would be attractiing problems.

Comment: Thanks it worked! @TheImpaler yes it was by accident